# Parse.Cloud.run not recognizing variables

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parse-server

I am trying to link my website to a Parse server using mongodb. It was running well, and saving so i could see in parse dashboard, and mlab. I attempted to add a new variable which resulted in me messing something up. When this get run it throws an error saying address is not defined on the line with Parse.Cloud.run.

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){

  var name = document.getElementById('inp1').value;
  var address = document.getElementById('inp2').value;
  var city = document.getElementById('inp3').value;
  var state = document.getElementById('inp4').value;
  var zipcode = document.getElementById('inp5').value;

  var Apartment = Parse.Object.extend("Apartment");
  var apartment = new Apartment();

  apartment.set("name", name);
  apartment.set("address", address);
  apartment.set("city", city);
  apartment.set("state",state);
  apartment.set("zipcode", zipcode);

  apartment.save(null, {
              success: function(apartment) {
                  // Execute any logic that should take place after the 
object is saved.

                  alert('New object created with objectId: ' + prod.id);
              },
              error: function(error) {
                  // Execute any logic that should take place if the save 
fails.
                  // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and 
description.
                  alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + 
error.description);
              }
          });
      });
Parse.Cloud.run("registerApartment",{"name":name,"address":address,"city": 
city, "state": state,"zipcode":zipcode,"map":map}, {
success: function(savedApartment){
 console.log(savedApartment);
}, error: function(error){
 console.log(error);
}
})
```

thank you ahead of time!

cloud code

```
Parse.initialize('#');
Parse.serverURL = 'http://localhost:1337/parse';


Parse.Cloud.define("registerApartment", function(req,res){
var params = request.params;
var name = params.name;
var address = params.address;
var city = params.city;
var state = params.state;
var zipcode = params.zipcode;



var Apartment = Parse.Object.extend("Apartment");
var apartment = new Apartment();

apartment.set("name", name);
apartment.set("address", address);
apartment.set("city", city);
apartment.set("state",state);
apartment.set("zipcode", zipcode);
apartment.set("map", map);

console.log(apartment);

apartment.save(null, {
success: function(savedApartment){
console.log("Succesfully saved bitch");
response.success(savedApartment);
}, error: function(error){
console.log(error);
response.error(error);
}
})
});
```

Comment: Does the variable `address` exist in the context where you call Parse.Cloud.run? Maybe the error message you mentioned refers to the parameter you pass to the function, not the server address.

Comment: Yes I have the 'inp#' connected to an input DOM tag in an html file. After I used document.GetElementById i console.log them and they return and still returns address is undefined. I used the github example Parse and in my main.js i have set all of the params with params.name, params.address etc

Answer (score 0):

could you double check your server where you define the cloud code?

Your code should be something along this line:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("registerApartment", function(req,res){
   ---your codes---
});
```

Make sure that your Parse.Cloud.run() is calling what you defined back at your server.

Edit:
Try to use this code instead of your current one:

```
Parse.Cloud.run("registerApartment",{name:name,address:address,city: 
city, state: state,zipcode:zipcode,map:map}, {
success: function(savedApartment){
 console.log(savedApartment);
}, error: function(error){
 console.log(error);
}
})
```

All i did was remove the quotes when parsing in a parameter. This should work fine :)

Comment: yea i have that in my syntax already. Not sure how else to call it. I got the params and set the variables to a new apartment object

Comment: Seems to me as though the address you entered is invalid OR on your cloud code, you did not retrieve/define the address from the values you sent over. Is it possible to paste your cloud code up for me to take a look?

Comment: I console.log the variables after I set the variables with document.getElementById("")  and it was successful yet stil brings up address not defined. Something is off with my apartment.set

Comment: Try commenting out your address in both cloud code and your front end and see if other values is being undefined

Comment: I just did that and now city is undefined. I believe it is my syntax for setting them into the apartment object.

Comment: It still did not get the defined address variable.

Comment: is your variable global or local? are you calling the Parse.Cloud.run() right after setting the variables into your db? try using this.address, this.name etc as your input values.

Comment: my variables are now local with no errors. Yet it is not sending or saving any info. It is not showing up in my parse dashboard, or in my powershell. My server is running.

Comment: I meant to state my variables were global

Comment: could you paste your cloud code? the one which u defined as Parse.Cloud.Define("registerApartment"); i believe you didnt get the parameters out from the cloud code. Undo the changes you did before and make sure it save into DB

Comment: Also, make sure at cloud code when you are retrieving the parameters out, use this: `req.params.name`

Comment: If you notice, your function you define as uses req and res. But your var params = request.params; change it to req.params instead :)